# Matlab function plot polinom derivative

Tags: matlab, function, plot

I will Implement a function named `plotpint` for plotting:

1. an nth degree polynomial p and
2. the derivative of p in the same plot.

I tried this but Ican't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function:

```
function [xPoints, pVal, dVal, dCoef] = polypint( coef, x1, x2, numpoints )

xPoints = linspace(x1, x2, numpoints); % Evaluation points
pVal = polyval(coef, xPoints); % Polynom values at the required xPoints

dCoef = coef(1:end-1).*(length(coef)-1:-1:2); % Derivative coefficients
dVal = polyval(dCoef, xPoints); % Derivative values at the required xPoints

plot(xPoints, pVal, xPoints, dVal)
grid on
legend('Polynom', 'Derivative', 'location', 'best')

end
```

You may call it with this simple code snippet:

```
coef = [1, -2, 0];
x1 = -1; x2 = 1;
numpoints = 1000;
[xPoints, pVal, dVal, dCoef] = polypint( coef, x1, x2, numpoints )
```

Comment: If you mean markers to plot points, you definitely need to check the help for plot function, since it contains every information you need about quick line options. For example, to place "x" markers the syntax is plot(x,y,'x')

Comment: I tried it doesn'twork . my marker code like this p=plot(xPoints,polValue,xPoints,dVal);
set(p(1),'Marker','.');
set(p(1),'MarkerSize',10);
set(p(1),'LineWidth',2);
set(p(1),'MarkerEdgeColor','b');
set(p(1),'MarkerFaceColor','g');

set(p(2),'Marker','d');
set(p(2),'MarkerSize',10);
set(p(2),'LineWidth',2);
set(p(2),'MarkerEdgeColor','b');
set(p(2),'MarkerFaceColor','g');

Comment: Sorry, I really haven't got time to debug this code without even knowing exactly what you mean to achieve. Please refer to [plot docs](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) for further help.